# Passing "< filepath" as argument to .exe

Tags: vbscript, cmd

What is the VBScript equivalent of running

```
my.exe --a=20 --b=NORMAL < file.txt
```

in a CMD?

When trying to pass a file as an input stream (not sure that's what it's called) to an .exe through a `WScript.Shell` object in a VBScript, it seems that the `< file.txt` part is interpreted as a part of the argument list (as opposed to an input stream).

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "my.exe --a=20 --b=NORMAL < file.txt"
```

The code above does not work in the same way as the command line argument at the top.

Comment: You need to pipe it through `cmd.exe` first as `<` is part of the command shell.

Comment: I interpreted "Pipe it through" as adding "cmd.exe " to the front of string, but all this does is open a new cmd. This is (obviously) not my strong suit - I would be very grateful for a working line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as lankymart says and use `cmd.exe` to interpret `>` as file redirection. `cmd /?` shows you use either `/c` or `/k` switch. So `cmd /c dir > file.txt`.

The VBScript way is to use the Exec method that returns `wshscriptexec` object allowing you access to stdout.

From Help

> Runs an application in a child command-shell, providing access to the StdIn/StdOut/StdErr streams.
>
> object.Exec(strCommand)
>
> object
>   WshShell object.
>
> strCommand
>   String value indicating the command line used to run the script. The command line should appear exactly as it would if you typed it at the command prompt.
>
> imageRemarks
>   The Exec method returns a WshScriptExec object, which provides status and error information about a script run with Exec along with access to the StdIn, StdOut, and StdErr channels. The Exec method allows the execution of command line applications only. The Exec method cannot be used to run remote scripts. Do not confuse the Exec method with the Execute method (of the WshRemote object).

And a sample from help reading StdOut

```
Dim WshShell, oExec, input
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec    = WshShell.Exec("test.bat")
input = ""

Do While True

     If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
          input = input & oExec.StdOut.Read(1)
          If InStr(input, "Press any key") <> 0 Then Exit Do
     End If
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

oExec.StdIn.Write VbCrLf

Do While oExec.Status <> 1
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: I'm sure your answer is a good one, but I'm not able to make the connection from this to what I can write to fix the issue. Could you add an example code showing how to call an .exe with arguments and the "< filepath"?

Comment: The point was you should do this the VBScript way if writing VBScript.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it the VBScript way.    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("my.exe")?

Comment: `>`, `<`, and `|` are interpreted by `cmd` only to do file redirection. Therefore you only lose those parts - `Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("my.exe --a=20 --b=NORMAL")`. Then read StdOut or write to StdIn. It's more work but more flexible and good training. **And less resource intensive** as you start one program rather than two programs. Program creation and window creation are the two areas in windows that uses most resources..

Comment: I should clarify I meant I was getting at the first part of the answer about `cmd.exe /c`. But agree `WshScriptExec` is a valid option, although it can be cumbersome to manage at times.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness (as this has only been hinted at in comments). Running the command doesn't work, because input redirection (or rather I/O redirection in general) is a CMD builtin feature. You need to run the command with `CMD.exe` to make it work:

```
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c my.exe --a=20 --b=NORMAL < file.txt"
```

In most cases [CMD redirection](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) is easier to handle and less error prone than using a [`WshScriptExec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object, unless you need your script to interact with a commandline program.